# NodeJS, Angular 2 | Executing method on Observable next

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm currently getting started with Angular 2 and got stuck on something probably pretty simple:

I have a shared service chatMessageService.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class ChatMessageService {


  private messageList = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  currentMessage = this.messageList.asObservable();

  constructor() { 
  }
  public addMessage(msg:string) {
    this.messageList.next(msg)  }
}
```

The service is imported by two components, one that calls it's addMessage function to add the message to the Observable and then my chatComponent.ts looks like this (shortened fpr convinience):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from './message';
import { ChatMessageService } from './chatMessage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})
export class ChatComponent  {


  conversation: Message[] = [];
  //.....

  constructor(private chatMessageService: ChatMessageService) { }

    addUserMessage(message) {
      this.conversation.push({
        content: message
      });


    }
    ngOnInit() {
      this.chatMessageService.currentMessage.subscribe(message =>    {this.addUserMessage(message);} )
    }


  }
```

My crisis arises at that last subscripion part. When I replace

```
{this.addUserMessage(message);}
```

with

```
{console.log(message)}
```

the message is printed out perfectly fine. If I call the addUserMessage()-method manually it works just fine. But when I call the method right there, with the message as argument, nothing happens. The method isn't even executed?

Thankful for your insights!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need some buffering in the service.
Instead of BehaviorSubject, try

```
private messageList = new ReplaySubject<string>(10);
```

See working example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oSCpcNkC6GHicuD7EfqH?p=preview)

Comment: That's the solution! Thanks a lot.